# How to form primary key pattern?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want primary keys in a table of a particular database with the following

```
pattern:
c11-4893
c11-4894
c11-4895
c11-4896
c11-4897 and so on....
```

What will be the query for it ?

Comment: Tag the only DBMS which is you really using.

Comment: Looks like it's just `ORDER BY columname`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just use an auto increment field (get rid of the letters and dash).  Why would you want that?

Comment: @dustytrash that is the syntax of a particular college ID, and want to make ID a primary key.

Comment: @Barmar that is the syntax of a particular college ID, and want to make ID a primary key.

Comment: @ALI So this column already exists with the data, and you want it to be the primary key?

Comment: @dustytrash I haven't the data in the table yet. But I want the same pattern of primary key in such a way that it gets auto-increment.

Comment: @ALI The answer posted should work for you. Curious though, why do you need the primary key to look like this?

Comment: @dustytrash I just got a challenge to try this XD.. Thanks anyways !

Comment: @ALI If it's a challenge I'd suggest trying it yourself first. You won't learn much otherwise..

Comment: And your way of meeting the challenge is to ask StackOverflow to do it for you? Nice.

Comment: @APC I search alot on google, but couldn't find a concrete result. Nevermind.

Comment: Isn't "c11-" superfluous? If all rows have it, what good does it make?

Answer (score 0):

Create an IDENTITY column to generate the number at the end, and then create a COMPUTED column that adds 'c11-' to the front of it and make the computed column your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are not meant to be visible or sexy. They are just a value that is unique per row. Heck, they don't even need to be consecutive, numeric, or even readable.

If you need the value to be visible, then you'll most likely **display** it. Then it will be **known** to people. Some time later it will be subject to **changes**, **formatting** and all kind of things. You don't want that to happen to the primary key.

Therefore, you probably don't need it as the primary key, but as a "secondary" identifier. You can use an extra column with a `UNIQUE` constraint to store this extra (visible and sexy) identifier.